# Redirecionar www para non-www

Tags: redirecionamento-de-url, subdomínio, www

Tenho um certificado SSL que segura

www.dominio.com.br

dominio.com.br

sub1.dominio.com.br

sub2.dominio.com.br

sub3.dominio.com.br

Porém existem links (na qual não tenho controle) que acessam os sub-dominios via WWW, ou seja, e neste caso o browser exibe uma mensagem de site não seguro pois meu certificado não cobre WWW para sub-dominios.

Como eu crio um redirecionamento somente para os sub-dominios de www para non-www independente se o acesso for via http ou https?

Tenho acesso total aos servidores de site e DNS.

Obs.: O módulo URL Rewrite do IIS não funciona pois o cliente continua acessando www.

Answer (score 0):

Se estes links (com www e subdomínio) forem com https, mesmo que você crie o redirecionamento, você vai obter erro de certificado, uma vez que precisará abrir o link para identificar que o mesmo está redirecionado.

Qual httpd você está utilizando?

Comment: O que é httpd? Uma entrada NAME (ou outra) no DNS não funciona?

Comment: httpd seria o http daemon, ou seja, servidor Web. Alguns comuns são Apache, nginx, IIS... O método de redirecionamento irá variar de acordo com o servidor utilizado.

Não é possível fazer este redirecionamento a nível de DNS. Um registro CNAME, que seria o mais próximo, iria requerer configuração adicional no httpd e ainda teria o problema do certificado inválido para os requests feitos via https.

Outra alternativa para o seu caso seria emitir um certificado que cobrisse estes domínios como SAN (Subject Alternative Name), que é o que você já deve ter para os subdomínios.

Comment: Estou usando o IIS 8.5. O que tenho direito neste certificado e que já está cadastrado são *.dominio.com.br e dominio.com.br

Comment: É que realmente, certificados wildcard tem um limite de profundidade, não funcionando em sub-sub domínios. O próprio stackoverflow sofreu com isso no passado: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/
O que te indico é corrigir os links, ou pelo menos retirar o SSL (https) deles, visto que sem o SSL pelo menos você consegue redirecionar para o subdomínio sem www. Com SSL, você sempre terá erros de certificado, não tendo como contornar isso.